NestJs dynamic module needs to be configured each time
I created a dynamic module and it works fine, but I encountered a problem when I wanted to add my dynamic module to more than one module. It requires adding configuration information each time. It creates a singleton of my service with the same config options, but I want to configure my module in the app module and then just import it into the other modules and use the exported service. Additionally, I don't want to use global options now. here is my module:
@Module({})
export class SmsModule {
  static forRoot(   options: Configs & { isGlobal?: boolean }  ): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: SmsModule,
      global: options.isGlobal,
      providers: [ { provide: NEST_SMS_CONFIG_OPTIONS, useValue: options }, SmsService ],
      exports: [SmsService],
    };
  }
}

here is my service:
@Injectable()
export class SmsService {
  private readonly smsProvider: string;
  private readonly api:  ExternalApi;
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(NEST_SMS_CONFIG_OPTIONS) private readonly options: Configs) {
    if ('apiKey' in this.options) {
      this.smsProvider = 'my-external-api';
      const apiKey = this.options?.apiKey;
      this.api = new ExternalApi({ apiKey });
    } else { throw new Error('Invalid SMS configuration options.') }
  }

the app module
@Module({
  imports: [ SmsModule.forRoot({ apiKey: "api-key" }) ],
})
export class AppModule {}

the auth module
@Module({
  imports: [ SmsModule ],
})
export class AuthModule {}

the auth service
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  constructor(private readonly smsService: SmsService){}
}

I get this error: Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the AuthService (?). Please make sure that the argument SmsService at index [0] is available in the AuthModule context.
Then I try to add SmsService to @Module() decorator before the SmsModule like below:
@Module({
  providers: [SmsService],
  exports: [SmsService],
})
export class SmsModule {
  static forRoot( options: Configs & { isGlobal?: boolean } ): DynamicModule {
    return {
      module: SmsModule,
      global: options.isGlobal,
      providers: [ { provide: NEST_SMS_CONFIG_OPTIONS, useValue: options }, SmsService ],
      exports: [SmsService],
    };
  }
}

"It throws an error because of an undefined option in the SmsService constructor function. When I remove the @Optional() decorator, I get this error:
Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the SmsService (?). Please make sure that the argument "NEST_SMS_CONFIG_OPTIONS" at index [0] is available in the SmsModule context.
I believe there's a way to leverage the 'NEST_SMS_CONFIG_OPTIONS' that I've injected into my service within the app module file, particularly when the SmsModule is imported using the 'forRoot' method. Essentially, in my scenario, the 'forRoot' method serves a similar purpose to the 'register' method.
I also took a look at NestJs ConfigModule source code, but I can't understand how exactly it is working.

Can you please provide a minimal repository so I can easily check what's wrong?

Sure, here is a minimal repository, Github Link

I'm not sure how to implement this, but you can try studying the NestJS's TypeORM code to see how they handled that. They configure the connection only once and then use TypeORM.forFeature() to get needed services. https://github.com/nestjs/typeorm/blob/master/lib/typeorm.module.ts
